How to fix weird cloth physics behaviour? (Armature + Cloth simulation)
I'm struggling to figure out why my dress glitches out when I move a hip bone. What happens is that after a hip moves, it bends in a weird way as if it had some weight painting but it doesn't.
The way I set up the physics is

I gave a cage cloth physics and added a Surface Deform modifier to the dress. There are actually 3 cages and 3 Surface Deform modifiers: one for each loose part of the dress that hangs down.
settings for the physics are mostly default (cotton preset). I've just added a pin group which are top vertices of the cage, so the armature can move the cage mesh.
each cage is a child of the COG control bone of the armature, so it moves with the model (Parent To > Bone ...)

Here is my model:



we can't inspect the file, so it's hard to tell, isn't it the pin group that holds vertices in place?

pls provide blend file because it can be a lot of reasons and you just showed a very little bit of information we would need to answer that. thx.

Hi, R1ck1s, I think we do need a share of the failing portion of your file, here, on https://blend-exchange.com/ , or we can't diagnose your problem. At the moment this post is vulnerable to being voted 'unclear'

The root of all evil here is that you bound the (cage) mesh with the cloth simulation to a bone. It looks like the Surface Deform modifier stops working properly when you do this. If you bind the mesh via vertex groups, everything is fine.
Other than that, there are a few other things you should fix/change because they can and will also cause problems.
Complete List of Fixes
Preparation and Clean Up


clear the (2) keyframes of the dress, body, legs, and the rest of the model. Only the armature and the cloth simulation should control the model.

unbind the Surface Deform modifiers of the dress using the Unbind button in the modifier settings

apply Scale and Rotation (Ctrl+A) to the dress, the model (body, legs, etc), and the 3 cages. Now the (1) Rotation and Scale values in the side panel should be (0°, 0°, 0°) and (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), respectively.

change the order of the modifiers. (3) + (5): the Armature comes first, followed by the Surface Deform modifiers, and the other modifiers come last. This way the armature deforms the mesh, then the Surface Deform modifiers do their job, and when the shape is final the other modifiers can add additional geometry.




optional: improve the topology of the dress. Add some cuts and dissolve the vertices to create a better quad structure. You can set the (4) Vertex Crease value to 1.0 for the selected corner vertex to make it pointy. (Or bevel the horizontal edge to split it into 2 support edges.)

turn the cages into planes because the Surface Deform modifier works with surfaces (while the Mesh Deform modifier works with cages). Just keep the front faces of the cage, delete the rest.

now it's time to delete the baked simulation data


Major fix, re-bind the cage/plane with weights to the armature

clear the parent of the "cage"/plane (it's now a plane) (Alt+P)
bind the cage/plane with weights to the armature. Choose a deformation bone like the hip bone instead of a control bone. (A deformation bone has the Deform option enabled so the armature can deform it.)
so, create the new vertex group (6) hip, select all vertices of the cage/plane, and add them with full weights (1.0) to the hip vertex group
finally, use Ctrl+P Parent To > With Empty Groups to bind the cage/plane to the armature
optionally, clean up: remove all unused vertex groups except hip and pin
change the order of the cage/plane's modifiers (7) to Armature first, then Cloth, so the cloth simulation follows the armature's movements
bake the cloth simulation (or at least refresh the cache by changing an option because it will be messed up now)
last step: Go to frame 1 (rest position) and rebind the dress mesh to the Surface Deform modifiers using the Bind button in the modifier settings


That's it. Now the Armature, Surface Deform, and the Cloth modifiers should work together.

Thank you so much for help it finally works! I also appreciate the additional tips.
